# Limiting vertical line length in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a forest plot with different groups. The code I'm using looks like the following:

```
d = data.frame(Estimate = c(1.8,1.9,2.1,2.4,2.7,2.5), 
               Group = rep(c('Group A', 'Group B'), each = 3),
               Method = rep(c('Method 1', 'Method 2', 'Method 3'), 2))
d$Lower = d$Estimate - 0.3
d$Upper = d$Estimate + 0.3
ggplot(data = d, aes(y = Group, x = Estimate, xmin = Lower, xmax = Upper, color = Method)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2, position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(2, 2.5), linetype = "dashed")
```

And the resulting plot:
[image]

The vertical lines (2, 2.5) are the true group means. I want to **limit these vertical lines to be within each group** (i.e., the first one from bottom to the middle, the second one middle to top). Anyone know how to do this?

I've tried `geom_segment()` function but I think it requires a numerical y input, while it's a factor here.

Comment: You can still use geom_segment. By default the y coordinates for Group A and Group B will be 1 and 2 (you can change this but that's the default). So you could use for example y = 0.75 and yend = 1.25 which would probably cover Group A but not B (note I didn't test this!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factors plotted on an axis are "really" numeric, but with labels added, so you can go ahead and add numeric segments:

```r
ggplot(data = d, aes(y = Group, x = Estimate, xmin = Lower, xmax = Upper, 
                     color = Method)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2, position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(y = c(0.67, 1.67), x = c(2, 2.5), 
                                 xend = c(2, 2.5),  yend = c(1.33, 2.33)), 
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Or, with a few tweaks:

```r
ggplot(data = d, aes(y = Group, x = Estimate, xmin = Lower, xmax = Upper, 
                     color = Method)) + 
  geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width = 0.5), size = 1) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, position=position_dodge(width = 0.5), shape = 21,
             fill = "white") + 
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(y = c(0.67, 1.67), x = c(2, 2.5), 
                                 xend = c(2, 2.5),  yend = c(1.33, 2.33)), 
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, linetype = 2) +
  annotate("text", c(2, 2.5), c(1.5, 2.5), size = 6,
           label = c("Group mean = 2", "Group mean = 2.5")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]